# How can I fix notification vibration?

Tags: notifications, 2.3-gingerbread, vibration

When I receive calls and alarms go off, the phone vibrates. 
However it won't vibrate for any notifications.

Changing the vibrate setting from vibrate always or vibrate only when in silent mode has no 
effect.

Does anyone know what can cause this and how to fix it? 
Is there a separate hidden setting for notification vibrations?

For what it is worth I'm running a HTC Magic with a custom 2.3-Gingerbread ROM installed.
This definitely used to work. Not sure what I did to break it though.

---

Update: I've got it working again by playing with the settings.

Under Settings->Sound settings->Volume 'Use incoming call volume for notifications' was ticked.

When I un-ticked this setting the notification vibration began to work again. This seems really strange to me and if anyone could help me understand what is going on it would be much appreciated.

---

Update 2: Installed an app called [AudioManager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidget&feature=search_result). It has separate vibrate checkboxes for alerts and ringer. Using this helped too. Not 100% but it seems to indicate separate settings that are not exposed through the regular settings interface.

Comment: Did this work before and stopped, or have you never had vibration working?  What phone do you have?  Are you using a custom ROM (and if so, which)?

Comment: I've updated the question to include this info.

Comment: The AudioManager suggestion was awesome -- I had the exact same issue and this also solved it for me. You should add it as the accepted answer to this question.

Comment: @Miquel Ok. Done!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install an app called [AudioManager](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.smartandroidapps.audiowidget&feature=search_result). It has separate vibrate checkboxes for alerts and ringer. Setting the checkbox for alerts fixed the issue for me.

Comment: Is there an open-source app that has the same functionality?

Answer (score 1):

You can have app-specific notification settings.  Have you gone into the settings of the offending apps to see whether they're set to vibrate on notifications?

Comment: Thanks but I have. GMail, Mail, Calendar, Messaging, all set up to vibrate but no vibration.

Comment: OK, I've asked some questions up above to help us troubleshoot further.

Comment: Hmm.  Well a factory reset *should* fix it but hopefully we can find something easier.

Comment: Even better ... get new phone! (Have to convince my wife first)